android tv box is not detected when it's connected to laptop via HDMI cable
I bought a Next Start Google android tv box. It runs well on TV via HDMI connection ( it's detected on AV Port)
When I connect it to my laptop via HDMI cable, it won't be detected in Displays list.
I ran
xrandr -q

it only list current screen resolutions of laptop display:
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 16384 x 16384
eDP connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 344mm x 193mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+
   1680x1050     60.00  
   1280x1024     60.00  
   1440x900      60.00  
   1280x800      60.00  
   1280x720      60.00  
   1024x768      60.00  
   800x600       60.00  
   640x480       60.00  
HDMI-A-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)

I want to watch tv box on the display of my laptop.
But how?

You can't. The laptop has a HDMI output. Your laptop can't receive a signal on the HDMI port and display it.
To display an incoming HDMI signal, you'd need what's known as a HDMI capture card.
